# This и его контекст

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, this

уважаемые пользователи. 
Хочу задать один вопрос, чтобы прояснить одну вещь, немного непонятную. Про то, куда указывает контекст

```
var object1 = {

    "attr1": function(){
        console.log(this);
        return 1+2;
    }(),

    "attr2": function(){
        console.log(this);
        return 1+2;
    },

    get "attr3"(){
        console.log(this);
        return 1+2;
    }
}

console.log(typeof object1.attr1);      //Тип Number, а This указывает на глобальный объект
console.log(typeof object1.attr2());    //Тип Function, а This указывает на объект object1
console.log(typeof object1.attr3);      //Тип Number, а This указывает на объект object1
```

Почему контекст attr1 указывает на глобальный объект?
Прошу прощения за такой глупый вопрос, сам никак не соображу

Comment: во втором случае не может быть тип Function, там тот же самый Number что и во всех остальных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему контекст attr1 указывает на глобальный объект? Прошу прощения
>   за такой глупый вопрос, сам никак не соображу

```
"attr1": function(){
    console.log(this);
    return 1+2;
}(),
```

Здесь сразу выполняется функция. В данном случае, в св-во `attr1` запишется именно значение, которое вернула функция ( получится 3 )
Функция же эта вызывается в глобальном контексте, так как объект еще не создан, идет только его инициализация

Если очень грубо упростить, то ваш код примерно равен вот этому коду:

```
var object1 = {};
object1.attr1 = function () {}();
object1.attr2 = function () {};
// и так далее
```

Вот тут главное отличие

```
// функция сначала вызовется, а только потом присвоится значение attr1
object1.attr1 = function () {}();
```

Comment: А в Get'e This указывает верно

Comment: @ДенисИванов геттер не вызывается при инициализации

Comment: аа так первая функция сразу вызываетсья благодарья скобкам сразу при инициализации ..я понял

Comment: @Избытоксусликов да

Comment: ThisMan, спасибо, я вспомнил это благодаря тебе. Точно, начальная инициализация при первичном чтении кода (что функции читаются первыми) и исполнение отдельных фрагментов кода